# need help targeting an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

this question has probably been asked before, but i'm stuck and i've tried a lot of different filters and I can't quite get the target that I need. I know it can be done, but i'm sort of confused with things like `:first` `:next:` `parent()` etc.

anyway, here's my basic structure...

```
<tr>
    <td>06-22-2012</td>
    <td>11.00</td>
    <td>Whatever</td>
    <td><i>whatever</i><br /><br /><span class='leaveAComment'>Leave a comment</span></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class='commentRow'>
    <td colspan=5>Comment:<input type='text'/><input type='submit'></td>
</tr>
```

when the span `.leaveAComment` is clicked, I want to toggle the visibility of the row `.commentRow`, which is initially hidden.

This is only a small section of a table. The closest i've gotten is `$('tr').next('.commentRow').toggle();` 
 but that toggles all the hidden rows, not just the next one.

any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
```

Get the closest tr, get the next tr, toggle it.

Comment: before I try this, I want to understand it.

So the closest tr to (this) is the one that the span is inside. then the next tr is the hidden one.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `.closest()` gets the first parent element that matches the given selector, so in this case it selects the first parent that is a tr element. We then use `.next()` to get the next table row, then we toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one leaveAComment and one commentRow:

```
$('.leaveAComment').on('click', function(){ $('.commentRow').toggle(); });
```

Comment: I guess that there are more than 1 `commentRow` in his code . It will hide everyone :)